# Count rows where two values appear together

Tags: excel

My data are in MS Excel:

```
  Col A Col B Col C Col D
1 amy   john  bob   andy
2 andy  mel   amy   john
3 max   andy  jim   bob
4 wil   steve andy  amy
```

So, in 4x4 table there are 9 different values.
I need to create table to find how many times each PAIR is occurring in the same ROW. Something like this:

```
      amy  andy  bob  jim  john  max  mel  steve  will
amy   0
andy  3    0
bob   1    2     0
jim   0    1     1    0
john  2    2     1    0    0
max   0    1     1    1    0     0
mel   1    1     0    0    1     0    0
steve 1    1     0    0    0     0    0    0
will  1    1     0    0    0     0    0    1     0
```

And I have no clue how to do it...
To reiterate: no duplicated values in each row, each row has unique values, each value in separate cell, so there are column with values and within column values can duplicate.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: I presume PAIR is to be checked in rows! Isn't it?

Comment: Yes... Just edited to reflect this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your data is in `A5:D8` I proceeded like this -

- created a helper column with the formula (copied downwards)

```
=A5&"-"&B5&"-"&C5&"-"&D5
```

- Named this helper column as `helper` (named range)
- listed down and across the unique combinations of names in `H4:P4` (across) and `G5:G13` (down)
- enter this formula in H5 and copy it both downwards and across to fill all `9x9` matrix

```
=IF($G5=H$4,0,COUNTIFS(helper,"*"&$G5&"*",helper,"*"&H$4&"*"))
```

Your desired matrix is ready

[image]

A detailed [blog](https://www.xlsoffice.com/others/count-paired-items-in-listed-combinations-in-excel/) is available on web for this.

Comment: To handle names that occur within names, eg Alex,  Alexander or  Elizabeth Beth (and liz) you would want the matrix of names to have leading and trailing hyphen and the helper column as well needs leading/ trailing hyphen